# What are all the multi-step tasks in The Skeld, Polus and MIRA HQ?

Tags: among-us

I would just like to ask a simple question: what are all the tasks in Among Us that has more than one step? (e.g. Empty Garbage (Cafeteria, Storage))

Answer (score 4):

Must be done in order unless specified otherwise. You can find information on every task [on the Among Us wiki](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Tasks).

### Skeld

- **Align Engine Output** (any order: Upper/Lower Engine)
- **Divert Power** (Electrical, random location)
- **Empty Chute** (O2, Storage)
- **Empty Garbage** (Cafeteria, Storage)
- **Fix Wiring** (Three random locations)
- **Fuel Engines** (Storage, Upper Engine, Storage, Lower Engine)
- **Upload Data** (Random location, Admin)

### MIRA HQ

- **Divert Power** (Reactor, random location)
- **Fix Wiring** (Three random locations)
- **Water Plants** (Storage, Greenhouse)

### Polus

- **Fix Weather Node** (Random location, Laboratory)
- **Fix Wiring** (Three random locations)
- **Fuel Engines** (Storage, Right Engine, Storage, Left Engine)
- **Open Waterways** (any order: Boiler Room x2, right of Weapons under Office)
- **Replace Water Jug** (Boiler Room, Office)
- **Upload Data** (Random location, Communications)

### The Airship

- **Divert Power** (Electrical, random location)
- **Empty Garbage** (Medical, Meeting Room)
- **Fix Wiring** (Three random locations)
- **Upload Data** (Random location, **unknown**)

The Airship is not released at the time of writing. This list may be inaccurate once it is released.

Comment: Please follow up on the Airship list once it is released. Otherwise, all good!